# Django hosting on heroku becoming a real trouble

Tags: python, django, heroku, cloud, hosting

Is there any work-around for this really?? am totally having a huge challenge hosting my django applications. If there is any simpler way of hosting django apps on any server please also suggest for me.

Even after what seemed at first as a successful host on heroku, I again got this error

> ---
>
> ***Application error

---

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

heroku logs --tail***

Comment: Indeed please, share error generated after running heroku logs --tail from your terminal, you could run heroku login before that, if not done so far, then it will be easy to give fix for your error,
I would suggest check static file dir error, most common error enountered when you are deploying for first time

Comment: Check this guide by Mozilla to set up Django for Heroku. There are many steps involved to deploy successfully: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment